# Package RQuantLib is not available for R 3.5.0

Tags: r

Has anyone else tried to load the RQuantLib package for R 3.5.0?

I tried (which has worked before):

```
install.packages("drat", dependencies = TRUE)
drat::addRepo("ghrr")
install.packages("RQuantLib", type = "binary")
```

but get the error message:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://ghrr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
```

cannot open URL 'https://ghrr.github.io/drat/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘RQuantLib’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0)

Comment: Someone would need to _build it_ first.

Comment: I'm not sure if its right, but I don't explicitly type it in.  I'm doing the  procedure listed in the RQuantLib github page: https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rquantlib, which says to type in the 3 lines I listed above.

Comment: Is there a way that I can help with that, or very nicely and politely ask..."pretty-please"....

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("eddelbuettel/rquantlib")
```

Or equivalently (based on comment by Dirk Eddelbuette)

```
install.packages("RQuantLib", type="source")
```

Comment: That is no different than using `install.packages("RQuantLib", type="source")`.

Comment: Absolutely, especially taken into consideration you're a developer of the package ;)

Comment: Actually there is ... as I am a little behind releasing to CRAN. In particular the Windows builds process may now be smoother.  I'll try to make a new release "soon".